# Angular - Google Chart rendering fails on page refresh

Tags: angular, google-visualization

I am using google chart to render charts on my angular app. This works fine for first time page visit but as soon as I refresh the page. The variables such as googleLoaded and and google becomes undefined.

I have used directive code from https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart/

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>  
    var googleLoaded = false;
    var googleChartsPackagesToLoad = ['geochart'];
</script>
```

**Here is the stackblitz url:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3av4p7

**Error on console:** 
[image: Error on console]

Comment: I am updated your stackblitz.Working perfect made some changes in index.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I updated your stackblitz.

I installed google map in my local system. I tested and it is working fine. So I replaced your `angular2-google-chart.directive.ts` file to current installed file.

Moreover, you have not properly initialized the script in `index.html` file in `<head></head>` tag. That is the problem. Please do the following steps in your html file.

index.html file,

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>  
    // !important: You want to give this variable(var googleLoaded = false;). This is used to run multiple chart in your jade.
    var googleLoaded = false;
    // !important: Define which chart packages to preload.Because this package uses ChartWrappers you can use any chart type that Google supports, but if it // isn't loaded it will load it on demand. 
    var googleChartsPackagesToLoad = ['geochart'];
</script>
</head>
<<body>
  <my-app>loading</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Working perfect your stackblitz after iam updating
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mn7d6q

Screenshot,

[image]

I hope it solves your problem.

Thanks,

Muthukumar